# How to rename files, as they are copied to a new location, with adf

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I am performing copy activity from `cosmosDB` to `Blob storage`, collections will be copied to storage as files. I want those filenames to be renamed with "collectionname-date". The file should have `name`, followed by `date` and `time` as suffix to that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say i can't find any ways to get the collection name dynamically,but i implement other your requirements. Please see my configurations:

1.Cosmos db dataset:

as normal to set

[image]

2.Blob Storage dataset:

configure a parameter for it:

[image]

Then configure the dynamic file path:

[image]

Pass the collection static name(for me is coll) for the `fileName` param.

[image]

3.Output in Blob Storage:

[image]